# PHP / Laravel Firebase Realtime Database updating a specific field

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update firebase realtime database using kreait/firebase-php package.

Here's my tree:

[image: Click here to see the image (not enough rep to post image)]

I need to update the child of `/detail/pesan/1/<unique ID>` which have `is_read` value of `false` and update it to `true`.

Here's part of my code:

```
        $database = $firebase->getDatabase();

        $id_pesan=1;

        /*
            Update Firebase is_read 
        */
        $update = ['/is_read'  => "true"];

        $updatePesan_1 = $database
        ->getReference('chat/detail/'. $id_pesan)
        ->orderByChild('is_read')
        ->equalTo('false')
        ->update($update);
```

But i get this error :

```
Call to undefined method Kreait\Firebase\Database\Query::update()
```

when I change it to get the value first then update / set it :

```
$updatePesan_1 = $database
        ->getReference('chat/detail/'. $id_pesan)
        ->orderByChild('is_read')
        ->equalTo('false')
        ->getValue()
        ->set($update);
```

I get this error :

> {"status":"error","error":400,"message":"Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"is_read\", for path \"/chat/detail/1\", to the rules"}

What I'm trying to do is filter / query database first to find child of specific tree which have is_read = false and update the value from "false" to "true".

Is it possible to do query of firebase database then updating it?

If yes how do I fix my code to achieve that?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear in that you need to define an index. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data and https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+"Index+not+defined"

Comment: For this:  ->getReference('chat/detail/'. $id_pesan), it reaches 1, but then you have to select the unique id as well and then it will have the access to the is_read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's my solution**

Okay so after many research and trial and error.

I did a couple of things :

1. Change the new rule to enable editing specific field on firebase database
2. Change the PHP code since I am unable to do filter / query then update. so I had to do it without filter / query and then updating data

**1. Changes to Firebase database Rule**

I change the rule to this :

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true,
"chat": {
  "detail": {
    "$id_pesan" :{
      ".indexOn": ["is_read"]
     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Some short explaination :
The data is stored in chat/detail///
since I need to be able to change what's inside  I added ".indexOn" : ["is_read"] I change the rule and put indexing inside chat/detail/.

**2. Change PHP code**

At first what I want to do is this :

1. Initialize Firebase
2. Set references
3. Do Update call while query-ing field (in 1 call)

But it seems the package doesn't support what I wanted to do. so instead what I had to do is I have to query the field and get the unique ID value first. Then I made it into an Associative Array, then use it to update Database

here's the new code

```
 //initialize
 $database = $firebase->getDatabase();

 //get value of all the unique ID
 $getValue = $database
        ->getReference('chat/detail/'. $id_pesan)
        ->orderByChild('is_read')
        ->equalTo('false')
        ->getValue();

//initialize Array
$update = [];

//make the array necessary to update the firebase database
/* 
     What the Array should looks like 
     <Unique ID>/<variable I wanted to change> => "<new Value>"
     Example :
     "-IUAYS678/is_read" => "true"
     "-JVHBY817/is_read" => "true"
*/
foreach($updatePesan_1 as $k => $v)
{
    $update[$k. "/is_read"]="true";
}

//Update the Firebase Database
$updatePesan_1_process=$database->getReference('chat/detail/'. $id_pesan)
->update($update);
```

I hope this helps